# Matrix pivots with unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm reading [this](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/determinants-cofactors.html) series of articles on matrix determinants.

It is said:

> Cofactor expansions are also very useful when computing the determinant of a matrix with unknown entries. Indeed, it is inconvenient to row reduce in this case, **because one cannot be sure whether an entry containing an unknown is a pivot or not.**

Could somebody elaborate this statement a bit? What does it mean if an entry containing an unknown is a pivot or not? As I understand pivots in Gaussian elimination, they are simply the first non-zero elements of rows when the matrix is in its row-echelon form. **So what does it mean if a matrix element with unknowns *is not* a pivot?** And how does it prevent or hinder us from using row reduction to find the determinant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a matrix like $$\begin{pmatrix} x & 1 \\ 1 & x \end{pmatrix}$$ If $x \neq 0$ then your pivot is in the first row but if $x = 0$ then the pivot is instead in the second row.

Also notice that if $x = 1$ then the matrix has rank 1 and if $x = 0$ then the matrix has rank $2$. So based on this observation we expect there to be something preventing us from row reducing to the identity matrix because if $x = 1$ that would be impossible.

I disagree a little with how the textbook is worded. You can still do *some* row reduction, you just can't divide by $0$ or by any quantity (like $x$) with the possibility of being $0$.

So here what I would do is subtract $x$ times the second row from the first row to get $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 - x^2 \\ 1 & x \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then swap the rows to get $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 - x^2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Now we can see that if $1 - x^2 = 0$ then the matrix has rank $1$ and otherwise the matrix has rank $2$.

Moreover, we know the determinant is $-(1 - x^2)$ since we did one row operation which did not affect the determinant and a second which multiplied it by $-1$.